# Having trouble transferring ListBox items while excluding items that already exist

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am creating an application in which the user selects a car model from a dropdown list, which will cause a ListBox of available features to populate from a database. The user has the option to select single features, select all features, remove a feature, or remove all features, which will transfer these features back and forth from the features available ListBox to the features selected ListBox. I have everything working fine but am having a hard time adding just the features from the features available list that don't already exist in the features selected list.

My C# code behind:

```
 protected void btnSelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lbOptionsAvailable.Items.Count; i++)

                if (lbOptionsSelected.Items.Contains(lbOptionsAvailable.Items[i]))

                {
                    lbOptionsSelected.Items.Remove(Items[i].ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    lbOptionsSelected.Items.Add(lbOptionsAvailable.Items[i].ToString());

                }
        }
```

This works fine if I try to add all the items when all the items are already selected but it won't add all the remaining items while excluding items that already exist if certain items already exist in the selected features list.

Comment: So when you press the button SelectAll what do you want to do? The name implies that you want to add everything to the selected option list.

Comment: You are correct. I am just having trouble excluding items that may already exist if selected individually.

Comment: If you want to add everything, what about clearing the destination and then add everything from the source?

Comment: That is what I am working on right now Steve. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

You are checking correctly if the list contains the item of index i , but shouldn't you just add and remove the item itself?

```
 protected void btnSelectAll_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < lbOptionsAvailable.Items.Count; i++)

                if (lbOptionsSelected.Items.Contains(lbOptionsAvailable.Items[i]))

                {
                    lbOptionsSelected.Items.Remove(lbOptionsAvailable.Items[i]);
                }
                else
                {

                 lbOptionsSelected.Items.Add(lbOptionsAvailable.Items[i]);

                }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If need to find a way to merge item between selected and unselected (items that need to be added).

I hope you work with DataTable.
DataTable provide filter option and merge API.
this will help your situation and debugging.
but you need to check and update selected item before merge item.
But please make sure using DataTable is not a light/simple way for your goal.

Using DataTable as below

```
dtData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(System.Int32)));
dtData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(System.String)));
dtData.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("selected", typeof(bool)));

string[] vList = new string[] { "A", "B", "C" };
DataRow dRow = null;
for (int index = 0; index < vList.Length; index++)
{
    dRow = dtData.NewRow();
    dtData.Rows.Add(dRow);
    dRow[0] = index;
    dRow[1] = vList[index];
    dRow[2] = false;
}

//don't miss binding "defaultView"
this.listBox1.DataSource = dtData.DefaultView;
this.listBox1.DisplayMember = "name";
this.listBox1.ValueMember = "selected";

dtData.Rows[0][2] = true;

//this will allow filter item that you don't need to show.
dtData.DefaultView.RowFilter = string.Format("selected='{0}'", bool.FalseString);
```

additionally, "select column" may need to updated base on user selection

```
for(int index = 0; index < this.listBox1.SelectedItems.Count; index++)
{
    DataRowView dRowView = this.listBox1.SelectedItems[index] as DataRowView;
    dRowView["selected"] = true;
}

//and merge with your Available items
DataTable dtNewItems = new DataTable();
dtNewItems.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("id", typeof(System.Int32)));
dtNewItems.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("name", typeof(System.String)));
dtNewItems.Columns.Add(new DataColumn("selected", typeof(bool)));

//and merge it
DataTable dtSelected = dtData.DefaultView.ToTable();
dtSelected.Merge(dtNewItems);
```